# vertex paint with a distance

Tags: vertex-paint

Vertex painting happens with a distance from the brush center and not immediately:

[image: demonstration of the issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is stabilizing of the stroke. Disable it in the tool settings.

[Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/brush/stroke.html#:%7E:text=Stabilize%20Stroke%20makes%20the%20stroke,checkbox%20found%20in%20the%20header.):

> Stabilize Stroke makes the stroke lag behind the cursor and applies a
> smoothed curve to the path of the cursor. This can be enabled
> temporary by holding Shift while painting or permanently by clicking
> the checkbox found in the header.